# Jquery link to show divs in sequence one at a time?

Tags: jquery, show

I have a page with 5 divs.  Only one of them is shown by default - the other 4 are hidden with css. I have a button that I'd like to be able to click and show an extra div *one at a time* in sequence.  So in other words... 1st click of the link shows div #2, the second click adds div #3, the third click would show div #4 and the final click would then have all 5 divs visible.

I'm fine with the show/hide aspect but how can I get the link to move on to show the next div in the sequence?

Comment: Maybe if you show little bit  of your code can be easier to help

Comment: This behavior is generally called a carousel, so you'd likely be able to find both plugins and tutorials on how to build them on the internet with a little bit of searching.

Comment: It's not really a carousel I was thinking of... see the two responses below. Thank you anyway :)

Answer (score 1):

A simple way to implement this would to number the divs by assigning Ids like div1, div2, div3 ...

Then it's simply a matter of keeping track of the count of visible divs. In the click event handler of the button, you increment the count and generate the id of the next div to be displayed.

Also add a check to see if the count of visible divs is equal to total divs to be displayed.

```
var visibleDivsCount = 1;
var totalDivsCount = 5


function DisplayNextDiv()
{        
    if(visibleDivsCount < totalDivsCount)
    {
        visibleDivsCount += 1;
        $("#div"+visibleDivsCount).show();
    }
}


$("#button").click(function(){
    DisplayNextDiv();
});
```

Comment: This is superb - exactly what I was looking for.  Many thanks :)  I've upvoted but don't have enough ranking for it to make any difference apparently :(

Comment: Shame...seems your question was downvoted. Sometimes it isn't the questions that matter but the responses and conversation they start...I'll upvote Ketan for you, and your question. Happy coding.

Answer (score 0):

You could always access the display of each div to get the value of the `display` property, since as far as I know the jquery `hide()` function simply sets the display to `none`, anyway.

You could write a function that checks these values - like another poster suggested it might be an idea to name your `div`'s using sequential id's like:

```
<div id="div-0"></div>
<div id="div-1"></div>
```

And so on...then build your jquery selectors in a loop and check the display property:

```
for (divNo = 0; divNo < numberOfDivs; divNo++) {
    if ($("#div-" + divNo.toString()).css("display") == none) {
        // Show this div and bail.
        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Nunchy... another great idea :)